# javascript offline storage across multiple sessions

Tags: javascript, database, web-applications, offline

I'm building a small offline application that requires a simple data table (a contacts list). Something I can save to and read from.

I've looked into a few libraries and they all seem to only store data for the current session, and not into a file e.g. a fake sql database.

Can anyone point me towards the right technologies to use?

I'm planning to interact with the data table with a basic html form and JavaScript.

**EDIT: Would switching to a different technology like Java be more fitting for my needs? Still not able to find a workable solution to hook up to HTML other than setting up a vagrant environment and hooking up to a MySQL db with php.**

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers contain localStorage, that can store data (permanently) inside user's browser (similar to COOKIES). Usually there is ~5MB (but may differ or may be completely disabled).

```
if (localStorage) {
    db_data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('db'));
    //... modify db_data
    localStorage.setItem('db', JSON.stringify(db_data));
}
```

(for JSON use JSON2 library: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js )

Comment: thanks, localStorage is fine, but I'm concerned about losing data (switching browsers, accidentally clearing cache etc.) Ideally I'd like to be able to read and write to a separate JSON or XML file, but that doesn't seem to be possible with javascript.